# Adding local docker-deamon to docker-machine?

Tags: docker, daemon

I have just installed an Ubuntu machine with a docker-daemon and I am able to run docker containers, after that I installed docker-machine and provisioned an ESX machine with docker2boot and I see this host when I run `docker-machine ls`.

The problem however is that I can only see the ESX docker host and the local docker-daemon is not listed when I run this command `docker-machine ls`.

So now my question is, how do I add my local docker-daemon to the docker-machine so when I run `docker-machine ls`, I can see my local daemon as default docker engine?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't add the local daemon to `docker-machine` as that tool is primary used create/provision Docker-enabled hosts and manage the environment variables required to connect to those remote daemons:

```
$ env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/deizel/.docker/machine/machines/default
```

To connect to a daemon installed locally, you can unset those environment variables:

```
unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
unset DOCKER_CERT_PATH
unset DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

Or in Bash, simply run `unset ${!DOCKER_*}`.

That said, you might have luck using the `none` driver. For example:

```
$ docker-machine create -d 'none' --url http://localhost:2375 default
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env default
$ docker-machine ls
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                     SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default    -        none           Running   http://localhost:2375           Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint
```

(I'm on MacOS so I can't really test it right now.)